# at [in, with] which + for one + to Infinitive: Grammatically illicit?

Tags: grammar

"He is looking for a school 'at which for his daughter to learn French'."

Some people say this sentence is bad and illicit because 'prenuclear'. Is it true?

(I know that "--- at which his daughter can learn French" is well-formed.)

I've found lots of this pattern:

> A: One Truth is a parent-free zone, and provides a great space **in which for us** to get to know each other better, to ....(omission)... (trinitychurchknebworth.org)
>
> B: Is this really the best situation **in which for him** to rehabilitate himself?  (International Catholic Univ.)
>
> C: It's just the right size **in which for me** to stack my potholders. (individual impression, Amazon.com)
>
> D: Everywhere were things **with which for us** to make fire. (oneida-nsn.gov)
>
> E: --(omission)-- provide children with safe boundaries **in which for them** to explore, develop and flourish. (Sarisbury Infant School, U.K.)
>
> F: The staff at the rescue center  --(omission)-- made it their mission to find this loving senior cat a home **in which for him** to spend his golden years. (CAT DEVOTION)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like that wording. I don't know if I'd call it "grammatically illicit", but I wouldn't hesitate to call it "awkward".

My suggested rephrasing would be:

> He is looking for a school **where** his daughter can learn French.

One common piece of writing advice is to get rid of unnecessary phrases. (See, for example, [Flabby Phrases](https://smartblogger.com/weak-writing/) and [Superfluous Phrases](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/eliminating-superfluous-phrases/). That's why I would change Example A from:

> One Truth is a parent-free zone, and provides a great space in which for us to get to know each other better.

to:

> One Truth is a parent-free zone, and provides a great space for us to get to know each other better.

or maybe even:

> One Truth is a parent-free zone, and provides a great space to get to know each other better.

Example C could be improved, too:

> **Original**: It's just the right size in which for me to stack my potholders.
>
> **Improvement**: It's just the right size for stacking my potholders.

One more. The rest will be left as exercises for the learner:

> **Original**: Everywhere were things with which for us to make fire.
>
> **Improvement**: Things for making a fire were everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My puzzlement, however, grew and deepened. Why A C D are bad, and BEF good? Same construction. I need some degree of grammatical consideration.

Comment: I didn't say B, E, and F were good. In fact, quite the opposite. I merely said that I would improve three of them, and not bother improving all six. Remember, a sentence can be grammatically correct yet still be terrible writing.